# How can I check if a value exists in another table's last N rows?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

`used` contains a list of used items. I don't want the item to be used again if it was one of the last 10 items used.

From some googling, it seems like I need a subquery but can't get it to work. Here is what I tried so far

```
$check = mysqli_query($db, 'SELECT `id` 
                            FROM (
                                SELECT `id` 
                                FROM `used` 
                                ORDER BY `id` DESC 
                                LIMIT 10) 
                            WHERE `item` = ' . $id);
```

Before this I was using the following

```
$check = mysqli_query($db, 'SELECT `id` 
                            FROM `used` 
                            WHERE `item` = ' . $id . ' 
                            ORDER BY `id` DESC 
                            LIMIT 10);
```

However, seems like that was only limiting the results by 10, so would always return `true` if an item had been used, even outside of the last 10

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to check if the item `$id` was in the last 10 items in the `used` table. This query should do that:

```
$check = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT $id NOT IN (SELECT item 
                                               FROM used 
                                               ORDER BY id DESC 
                                               LIMIT 10)");
```

This query will return `1` if the value of `$id` was not in the last 10 values of `item` in the `used` table, or `0` otherwise.

For versions of MySQL which don't support `LIMIT` in `IN` subqueries, you can use a `LEFT JOIN` as in this query which will return the same result:

```
SELECT IF(b.item IS NULL, 1, 0) 
FROM used a 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT item 
           FROM used 
           ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10) b ON b.item = a.item 
WHERE a.item = $id
```

Comment: Thanks. Can't get this to work due to the following, "This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery" but I think I found a fix for that, didn't know about (NOT) IN.

Comment: @cantsay I've added an alternate solution for earlier versions of MySQL

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a JOIN:

```
$check = mysqli_query($db, 'SELECT u.id
FROM used AS u
JOIN (
   SELECT id
   FROM used
  ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10) AS ub
USING (id)
WHERE item = ' . $id);
```

Answer (score 1):

This works if your version does not support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery":

```
$check = mysqli_query($db, 'SELECT `item` FROM
                    (SELECT `item` 
                    FROM `used` 
                    ORDER BY `id` DESC 
                    LIMIT 10) as useditems
                    WHERE `item` = ' . $id );
```